# Rename files with a suffix with name of its folder

Tags: bash

Each folder has a `.mkv` or `.avi` file.

E.g:

```
Sommerferien201308/eins.avi
Sommerferien201309/eins.mkv
Herbst201401/film.avi
Herbst201402/krz.mkv
```

Renaming to:

```
Sommerferien201308/Sommerferien201308.avi
Sommerferien201309/Sommerferien201309.mkv
Herbst201401/Herbst201401.avi
Herbst201402/Herbst201402.mkv
```

How can I rename the filename to the name of its folder?
 Of course every foldername is unique. And too much to do it manually for each file/folder.

I Would try with find.

```
find . -type d -name "" -exec cd "" && mv {} \;
```

But i dont know how to select the folder name and how to make the .avi or .mkv selection and how to store the selected folder name..

Comment: One folder is named **Sommerferien2013** and the Videofile **eins.mkv**
I have many of them and sometimes there is .mkv or .avi or whatever. 

I would start with a `find` command?
The output would be **Sommerferien2013\Sommerferien2013.mkv**

Comment: Imagine you're someone else and you come across this question. Would you say all the necessary information is available to give a good answer?

Comment: Okay thank you for explanation i tried to make it more precise. Please give feedback if the question is not better understandable

Comment: It's much better now. However, one thing remains unclear: Where does recursion fit in?

Comment: That was my "idea". Because the script has to look in the folder if there is a mkv or avi file and then rename with mv. I thought when there are many of this folders then this will be done recursively?

Comment: That's *iteration*. It would be recursion if you stepped into directories and did *the same thing* inside them.

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you! More clear now. I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `find` command from base folder of your folders that contain `*.avi` and `*.mkv` files:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
(
   IFS=/
   arr=($f)
   if [[ $f != *"/${arr[len-2]}"* ]]; then
      len=${#arr[@]}
      ext="${arr[len-1]##*.}"
      cd "$(dirname "$f")" && echo mv "${arr[len-1]}" "${arr[len-2]}.$ext"
   fi
)
done < <(find . \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' \) -print0)
```

When you're satisfied with the output remove `echo` before `mv`.

Comment: Thank you. How to use it? I create a .sh file in the folder containing all other folders? and paste it in the .sh file? I tried it and then executed `$sh rename.sh`. 
Following output came
  `rename.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
rename.sh: line 9: `done < <(find . \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' \) -print0)'`

Comment: Great! That gives me output when i execute it. what is the `-o` switch in the find command? If i intend to extend with .mp4 ?  I dont find `-o` in the manpages of my OS. Edit: i found it. An OR Expression. :)

Comment: i removed the `echo` and i got this error `mv: cannot stat `sommer.mkv': No such file or directory`  what can i do?

Comment: Look at the `bash -x` (debug mode) output. `cd "$(dirname "$f")"` takes care of changing directory into each directory before running `mv` command.

Comment: hi @anubhava, why did you remove the post how to call the script in a non bash shell?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't remove anything from my answer.